# Can you clean install ubuntu (clean install, complete wipe ) if using Wubi?

Tags: wubi

I'm currently using a dual boot Windows Vista and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Wubi install) and I was wondering how to completely wipe the hard drive and install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS standalone.

PS. my computer has a S.M.A.R.T warning on it, removing the USB boot feature, and I don't have the ability to obtain blank DVD's.

So can I use `unetbootin` or something similar? I really need help, because Vista only runs in recovery mode.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc5e4cda2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    12840959     6419456   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    12840960   312576704   149867872+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 4007 MB, 4007657472 bytes
5 heads, 32 sectors/track, 48921 cylinders, total 7827456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        8064     7827455     3909696    b  W95 FAT32
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the ISO of 12.04 from the Ubuntu website and use Unetbootin to create the USB.

Then boot into the Live CD and what I would do here is open up gparted and just delete all the partitions and make  new one in the format of EXT4.

The just install Ubuntu as normal, selecting the "use entire HDD" option.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm trying to make a livecd, usb doesn't work, and whenever i write with bransero or whatever its named, this error pos up "scsi error on write(23856, 16): [5 21 02] Invalid address" any help?

Comment: I would format you USB using gparted the you can try using the CLI and the `dd` command. So if you run: `sudo dd if=/path/to/image.iso of=/dev/sdX`. Change X for the letter of you drive. You can get this from gparted

Comment: S.M.A.R.T. warning disables the choice to boot from usb for some reason, and i can't figure out how to get rid of it? Please help with that too.

Comment: You should be able to disable S.M.A.R.T from you BIOS. What motherboard are you using?

Comment: A Phoenix, i've looked through the BIOS, and its not in there, i'm on a sony Vaio laptop, btw.

Comment: What model of Vaio?

Comment: Model: PCG-7X1L

Comment: The SMART drive operates above BIOS...which is why BIOS has no function to control it. Try downloading this: [S.M.A.R.T. Monitoring Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartmontools/?source=navbar) Install and then run `smartctl -- smart=off -- saveauto=on /dev/hdX` Changing X for the appropriate letter.

Comment: what do you mean like c?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Changing x for the appropriate letter, do you mean like the drive name, like "C:/"?

Comment: also, how do i install smartmontools, i've already downloaded it

Comment: You need to unpack, build and install. Run these command in terminal: **To Unpack:** `tar -zxvf Downloads/smartmontools-6.1.tar.gz` **To Build:** `cd smartmontools-6.1` + `sudo apt-get install build-essential` + `./configure` + `sudo make` + `sudo make install`. THE `make` AND `make install` MAY TAKE SOME TIME.

Comment: ERROR: smartctl takes ONE device name as the final command-line argument.
You have provided 4 device names:
smart=off
--
saveauto=on
/dev/hdc

Use smartctl -h to get a usage summary

Comment: can you help with that? thats what happens when i type the command into teminal

Comment: you need to delete the space after the two `--` and change the deivce. So: `smartctl --smart=off --saveauto=on /dev/sdX` remember to change X to your device letter

Comment: Plug in your USB and type `sudo fdisk -l` into a terminal and edit you question to add what is returned. This way we can find out what your X is.

Comment: so, i updated the question, where do i find the letter?

Comment: Just to make sure it is a 4GB USB? If so, your X is b.

Comment: yeah, but my harddrive is failing, not the flashdrive

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. X is a

Comment: Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: Permission denied

Comment: try `sudo` at the start of the command

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, it worked, now tomorrow, i'll do a full ubuntu install with a livecd i made (Precise just barely fit, 7mb was left on the cd. Thanks so much again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please mark the question as answered, if you are happy. ;) Thanks

Comment: oh, and will the disable of smart carry over when i full clean install ubuntu, or will i need to redo this again?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I do think S.M.A.R.T will stay off. But if you have any problems, just let me know.

Comment: didn't work, i rebooted my pc, this is what it said "Failure predicted on Hard Disk 2: WDC WD1600BEVT -22ZCT0- (S1) WARNING: Immediately back-up your data and replace your hard drive. A failure may be imminent. PRESS F1 TO CONTINUE."

Comment: What happens if you hit f1?

Comment: it takes me to windows boot manager, where i can select windows vista for ubuntu (wubi)

Comment: @BiggJJ - please update your answer - its very difficult to follow what the current situation is with regards to your answer.

Comment: @Nick - the way we respond to queries and suggestions is by editing your question with what you have tried.  Please do so now - and then we can tidy up by deleting this very lengthy comment thread.  Thanks.

Comment: I did try and switch it to chat, but @Nick doesn't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) you can see a few ways to install Ubuntu.

For example "[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot) HOWTO describes the steps required to start an installation of Ubuntu over the network. This is useful, for example, if you have an old machine with a non-bootable CD-ROM."

After you have the installation going on, you can can chose to install Ubuntu alone.

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it, if i can't boot from cd, precise barely fit onto a standard 700mb cd

Answer (score 0):

> Can you clean install ubuntu (clean install, complete wipe ) if using Wubi?

While using Wubi, no. While using Windows, no. Using a Live CD/USB, yes.

> how to completely wipe the hard drive and install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS standalone

Just while installing tell the installer to use your full Hard Disk, that will remove anything and will install Ubuntu.

> my computer has a S.M.A.R.T warning on it, removing the USB boot feature, and I don't have the ability to obtain blank DVD's.

Depending of the message, this means that your hard drive is failing or almost failing, or you can ignore it. Remember to always have backups at hand.